# Clear page cache in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I clear a page cache. I tried impelemnting cache but switched it off, now my home page always loads the cached version. I tried the following rake task no luck.

```
namespace :cache_clear do
    desc 'clear a page cache'
    task :expire_cache => :environment do
        ActionController::Base::expire_page('/')
        puts "Cache cleared"
    end
end
```

Here is my home page code, it shows partials that essentially present collection of other models. Does this have something to do with it?

```
<div class="span-17 last">
<%= render :partial => "top_votes" %>
</div>

<% content_for :right_nav do %>
  <%= render :partial => "latest_votes" %>
  <%= render :partial => "whos_voting" %>
  <%= render :partial => "top_voters" %>

<% end %>
```

I even tried to expire the cache from a sweeper,

in my vote_topic controller I have

cache_sweeper :home_sweeper

```
class HomeSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
    observe VoteTopic
  def after_index(vote_topic)
    expire_cache(vote_topic)
  end

  def expire_cache(vote_topic)
     expire_page :controller => :home, :action => :index
  end
end
```

That doesn't work either, I do have cache turned off in my development.rb file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page cache is always on disk, so you will need to actually clear out the files/directory you want to flush.  It's an unfortunate way to cache.

```
 cache_dir = ActionController::Base.page_cache_directory
 unless cache_dir == RAILS_ROOT+"/public"
   FileUtils.rm_r(Dir.glob(cache_dir+"/*")) rescue Errno::ENOENT
 end
```

Comment: Hmm..Thanks. ActionController::Base.page_cache_directory is actually the public directory. Is this where the cache should be stored? Is this configurable?

Comment: It should be configurable.  You may want to move it to a subdirectory of public so you can more easily clear it out (like the example above)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. When using memcached, this works:

```
desc "Expire page cache"
task :expire_pages => :environment do
  ActionController::Base::expire_page("/")
  Rails.logger.info("Removed page cache")
end
```

Comment: Scott Montgomerie answer is correct I also do expire my html banners cache with the same code from a Rake task. I'm using memcached as well and there is no connection between the method of page caching and the other ones using memcached.